# TS2339: Property 'isChange' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance >>'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this problem, it asks me to type the variable but when typing it the error persists

[image]

and the variable
[image]

Comment: The question shouldn't be asked in general. TS may behave differently with different tools. You showed IDE but it's unknown if this happens on build. If it occurs in IDE only, this is IDE problem.

Comment: i am using visual studio